# getting an odd text box error when resetting form?

Tags: vba, userform

Using this code (below) to reset all fields within a userform:

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
Dim iControl As Control
For Each iControl In Me.Controls
    If iControl.Name Like "txt*" Then iControl = vbnullstring
    If iControl.Name Like "cmb*" Then iControl = vbnullstring
Next
End Sub
```

and I have one text box (one that's converted to a %) that isn't resetting, but showing this:

`-nan(ind)00.00%`

any idea how to prevent this and clear the textbox?

Comment: By calling `iControl = ...` effectively you are setting the `.Value` property of the control (default property). Since the value property is a variant, you should set it to `Null` instead if `vbNullString`. The latter is used on strings only.

Comment: Also, unless you want to clear only specific controls, to clear all textboxes and combos, you can call `If TypeName(ctl)="TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) "ComboBox" Then ...`.

Comment: @KostasK. hey, thanks a lot! Setting the iControl's to `Null` worked. not sure if you want to create an answer so i can give you credit, but thank you!

Comment: Glad it's sorted. You can post an answer on how you solved the issue and accept it. Your post will then be complete. Once you do, I'll delete this comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
Dim iControl As Control
For Each iControl In Me.Controls
    If iControl.Name Like "txt*" Then iControl = Null
    If iControl.Name Like "cmb*" Then iControl = Null
Next
End Sub
```